# Am Having trouble setting up flutter and running first program

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I installed flutter, android studio and everything compiles until it comes to compileflutterbuild debug, it always fails when it comes to this stage, it always display error with non zero return value, am really stuck here[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98loe.png)

I have tried running flutter upgrade major versions and i got this message[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaNBn.png)
[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPT11.png)

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-NG)
Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Chrome - develop for the web
Android Studio (version 2022.3)
Connected device (2 available)
Network resources
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://cocoapods.org/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware
installed on your computer.
X An HTTP error occurred while checking "https://github.com/": Connection closed before full header was received

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Show the output of "flutter doctor"

Comment: i have just added the flutter doctor image

Comment: Also rather add the output in the commands on text instead of on an image, makes it easier to copy and paste

Comment: i just added the flutter doctor output in text